# how do I get the proper coordinates?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent, windows-11

There's a form where I need to click on the "go" button, moving mouse to there and perform mouse click. But the coordinates I'm getting is off for some reason, it moves to mouse cursor near the top of the tab rather on button.

the HTML looks like this:

```
Nome: <input type="input" id="firstName">
<input type="button" value="Hit me" id="go" onclick="alert('Hello, ' + document.getElementById('firstName').value)"/>
```

my code goes like this:

```
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("go"));

    int browserWindowX = driver.Manage().Window.Position.X;
    int browserWindowY = driver.Manage().Window.Position.Y;

    Point elementLocation = element.Location;
    int x = elementLocation.X;
    int y = elementLocation.Y;

    // Calculate absolute screen coordinates
    int absoluteX = browserWindowX + x;
    int absoluteY = browserWindowY + y;

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    doClick(absoluteX, absoluteY);
```

`doClick` is defined as:

```
    void doClick(int x, int y)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (uint)x, (uint)y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)x, (uint)y, 0, 0);
    }
```

IWebElement is from Selenium library. I'm using WINAPI here because regular Selenium methods didn't work in this case.

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not click the button using `element.Click()`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt it's not working in the original page so I'm trying other approach

Comment: I think you'll be getting coordinates relative to the viewport...  you're trying to get them relative to the desktop screen...  I would make all these JS calls... first scroll into view.  Then get the location relative to the window, then try to adjust for the desktop, browser controls, etc...

Comment: @pcalkins how do I get those raw coordinates that you can get say using inspect.exe? JS's getBoundingClientRect() return very different coordinates

Comment: It's not going to be easy... especially if this needs to work on multiple machines/browsers.  You can't get the "raw" coordinates, but you can get coords via JS relative to the top/left of the viewport.  But then you must account for the space between the top/left of the viewport and top/left of the desktop.   The fact that you got those coords, means this element is in the DOM, though, so really not sure why you aren't using Selenium to click it.  It'll be easier to deal with whatever issue is causing the click method to fail.